# Summation of Integrals without using $\zeta(2)$

Tags: integration, summation, riemann-zeta

How do you evaluate the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{\sqrt k}^{\sqrt{k+1}} \left(\frac{x^2}{k}-1\right)\, dx$$

without using $\zeta(2)$?

I can see some relationship to $\dfrac1{\lfloor x^2\rfloor}$ and furthermore with $\dfrac{x^2}{\lfloor{x^2}\rfloor}-1$, but I didn't make much progress this way either.

Comment: What do you mean by "without $\zeta(2)$"?

Comment: @clathratus, I was trying to solve the Basel Problem in a way that was intuitive to me and can help me expand my knowledge of creating solutions. I was curious if this dissection of $\integral{\lfloor{x^-1}\rfloor}$ I derived from an identity using the Polygamma function could provide any information into the nature of the function.

Comment: I think you could help us help you by show us how you got from $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac1{k^2}$$ to $$\sum_{k\geq1}\int_\sqrt{k}^\sqrt{k+1}\left(\frac{x^2}k-1\right)dx$$. Also it might help you to note that $$\int_\sqrt{k}^\sqrt{k+1}\left(\frac{x^2}k-1\right)dx=\frac23\sqrt{k}+\frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{3k}(1-2k)$$